# How to implement Just in Time Routing on our lightning node

Tags: lightning-network-daemon, lightning-routing, ln-channel-balance-management

Can anyone here tell me how to implement "Just in Time Routing" for our lightning node?

We are running Umbrel for our node so if this is possible / feasible can it also be automated?

Thank you. :)

Orange_Bonzo